# Pulled an Android project from GitHub. Android studio doesn't load "support.v7 library"

Tags: android, git, github, android-support-library

So my coworker uploaded a project to GitHub which i pulled. I expected everything to be okay, but for some reason it won't load v7 support library (it gives sqiggly red lines under the v7 import)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

EDIT:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Does it actually build okay (and just display errors in the editor), or are there build errors as well? If the former, what version of Android studio are you running? If it's the latter, please post the build.gradle file for the module in question.

Comment: @ScottBarta It doesn't build okay. It cannot get support library, so it can't extend ActionBarActivity which is essential.
Here is the build.gradle http://pastebin.com/wX00LTZQ

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Android Support Repository is installed in your SDK manager:

[image: SDK Manager screenshot showing Android Support Repository entry]

Comment: I tried that. It was already downloaded, but I downloaded it again anyway. No help

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, you have to import the support libraries into your workspace by clicking "file" "import" and then browsing to wherever the SDK lives on your computer ... adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030>sdk>extras>android>support>v7 (for the root directory).  Then some projects should appear in the "Projects to import" window.  Select the ones you need and then select "finish".  Once they are in your work space, select your project that needs them and right click it and select "properties".   Then a window pops up. Select "Android" on the left and then in the bottom box select the v7  support libraries that you need and select "add", then "OK."   Now you have to rebuild your project and the red squiggly lines should go away. Yay!

Comment: This page is helpful: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html AND Android dependencies has to be at the bottom of the java build path (in "order and export") if it is not checked (as for libraries).  Also want to note that you do not have to included the appcompat libraries to your project since you already include them in the mediarouter library.